Passive filter design from transfer function
I would like to implement a passive RIAA filter circuit. This is the bode plot of a RIAA equalizer.

The transfer function of this:
H(jw) = (jwT1 + 1)/[(jwT2 + 1)(jwT3 + 1)] where time constants are defined: T1=318us, T2=3180us, T3=75us
So there is one zero and two poles.
The circuit can be implemented in several ways, but I would like to implement it in the circuit below:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I determined the transfer function of the circuit, which is as follows:
H(jw) = jw[(R2(C1+C2)]+1/[jw^2(R1R2C1C2)+jw(R2C1+R2C2+R1C2)+1]
The zero can be easily determined 1/[R2(C1+C2)], so T1=R2(C1+C2)
The poles are given by the solution of the quadratic equation.
My question is how can I determine the component values based on the transfer function?
Many people know how to determine poles and zeros by seeing the circuit, how?

Why not take a rough guess at approximate values and simulate it?

I assume you're doing this for your own personal education, because surely there must be thousands of articles describing every detail of every type of RIAA equalization circuit.

pipe: Yes, this is for my own personal education to understand filter design.

@slimcolt Also, how do you expect to get $+20:\text{dB}$ of gain from a passive network? (I would like to know. I think I could make bank on the idea if you share it with me.)

periblepsis: The equation has two real roots. So I think you're wrong about that. The circuit was the example, anything else could have been. I have studied many books, etc., but in most cases the derivation of the equations is missing. To fully understand, I need to know everything step by step. +20dB amplification is impossible with a passive circuit, but you know what to imagine for the output of the circuit, an operational amplifier with 10x amplification! :) If you don't know the answer to my question either, I think we'll leave the word battle behind.

@slimcolt Try $R_1=1:\text{k}\Omega$, $R_2=83.32:\Omega$, $C_1=977:\text{nF}$, and $C_2=2.93:\mu\text{F}$ for example. Yes, I know the solution space. Assuming of course a gain of 1 near DC, which your chart doesn't show.

@VerbalKint's response here should help out with obtaining poles and zeros by inspection.

@RussellH I gave him the transfer function. (A version of it, anyway.) Won't need to use VerbalKInt's method -- though I sincerely appreciate Christophe P. Basso's efforts to pay forward all that Dr. Milddlebrook has given to us (plus Basso's own excellent contributions, as well.) I was very much saddened when Dr. Middlebrook died. Luckily, his wife made much of his material available to us, then, for a very small fee. She stepped in to help when it mattered. Appreciated.

@slimcolt if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Here is one way of doing it by inspection.
At really low frequencies, capacitors are open. At really high frequencies, capacitors are shorts.
Think of your circuit as a voltage divider.  At dc and low frequencies, your circuit has a gain of one.
At middle frequencies, you want a flat frequency response (that is, a resistive voltage divider), with an attenuation of 20db or ten times, at some frequency when C2 is like a short and C1 is like an open, your circuit is a resistive voltage divider with a gain of R2/(R1+R2).  This quantity must be 1/10.
Choose some nice value for R1, say 10k or so. Now you can calculate R2.
At some higher frequency than the flat area, C2 will still be a short, but C1 will not quite be an open. You want C1 to create a rolloff at 2khz. From C1’s point of view, it sees the resistors R1 and R2 in parallel.  ( this is because C2 is a short and Vin is a stiff voltage source, a short for small signals). This frequency is 1/(2pi(R1||R2)*C1). So now you can calculate C1.
At really high frequencies, your circuit has an RC rolloff that begins at Freq=1/(2piR1*(the two caps in series). You want the attenuation at 20khz to be 40db.  This tells you that the rolloff begins two decades before this, or 200hz.  Now you know the two caps in series, so you can calculate C2.

The transfer function solution for your circuit is the following KCL result:
$$\frac{s\,R_2\left(C_1 + C_2\right) + 1}{s^2\,C_1\,C_2\,R_1\,R_2 + s\left(C_1\,R_2 + C_2\,R_1 + C_2\,R_2\right) + 1}$$
It's obvious from the above that \$T_1= R_2\left(C_1 + C_2\right)\$. Find the roots for the denominator using the usual, well-known quadratic equation can then get \$T_2\$ and \$T_3\$. I'm sure you can handle the algebra.
That's all there is to it. Three equations, three unknowns, one specified value. So given any one value, the other three can be found. There are a few more interesting ratios to find. But they aren't necessarily important. Just interesting.


Many people know how to determine poles and zeros by seeing the
circuit, how?

Yes, and this would be my preferred method. So, it's easy to get stuff on RIAA equalization circuits on-line and here's one that's nearly what you want (ignoring the op-amps): -

It has, as expected, the standard response: -

So, use a simulator and make the above response a template for comparison with your circuit's spectrum. Like this (about 5 minutes messing around): -

The red line is the one that's from your circuit and, it's pretty close to the blue line (the reference). Probably within about 0.5 dB. But you could tweak it a tad more and get it exact if you were an audiophile.
